# Send email through powershell not working

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm working on a script to send email to people through powershell. It send well on some computer, but on others it doesn't send at all I know that both computers are not configured exactly the same.

I can't figure why.

I tried adding 2>> c:\error.txt at the end of the command and it is not logging anything.

My code (I changer the smtp and email for confidentiality reasons):

```
            File.Delete(@"C:\Temp\Email2Send.ps1");
            var strVar_EMAIL_BOX = "myemail@email.com";
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\Email2Send.ps1");
            tw.WriteLine("$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding");
            tw.WriteLine("$smtp = \"forwarder.mail.xxxxxx.com\"");
            tw.WriteLine("$to = \"" + To + "\"");
            tw.WriteLine("$from = \"" + strVar_EMAIL_BOX + "\"");
            tw.WriteLine("$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8");
            tw.WriteLine("$subject = \"Suivi\"");
            tw.WriteLine("$body = \"" + Body + "\"");
            tw.WriteLine(@"send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $to -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -Encoding $enc 2>> c:\errors.txt");
            tw.Close();
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @"/C powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -command c:\Temp\Email2Send.ps1";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

EDIT : Nevermind I found the solution 2 seconds after posting. for some reason powershell is not linked correctly on some computer in the windows path. Changed powershell to : %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Comment: why are you using cmd to run powershell? powershell is already an executable. running cmd just to run powershell is redundant.

Comment: Why are you using C# to send email through PowerShell when C# has a perfectly good [SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class?

Comment: Yeah I use Powershell because email sending with c# is blocked on this network. it's just weird...

Comment: That makes no sense. The network doesn't know what is sending the email. It's just network traffic over port 25.

Comment: yeah I'm not the first programmer to try it. It's the security somewhere that does not accept it we don't know why. Big corp with a lot of security... The only way we found is to go with powershell

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution 2 seconds after posting. for some reason powershell is not linked correctly on some computer in the windows path. Changed powershell to : %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe